# HTML/CSS How to set full height in safari?

Tags: html, ios, reactjs, safari, flutter-web

How to set full height in web for safari, look like has some extra safe area from safari (ios) when search bar is hiding. can't fully scroll the page. here is the demo:

[image]

Comment: are both reactjs and flutter-web tags needed ?

Comment: i use flutter web also but different app, has the same issues. sorry